# Relation of the Heat kernel and the solution of the discrete diffusion equation

Tags: discrete, diffusion

As is well known, the solution to the continuous 1D diffusion equation $\partial_t f=D\,\partial_x^2 f$ is given by the Heat kernel
$$f(x,t)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/4Dt}}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}} \ .$$
On the other hand, the solution to the space-discrete/time-continuous diffusion equation $\dot f_k=\mu(f_{k-1}-2f_k+f_{k+1})$ is given by
$$f_k(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-2\mu t} I_k(2\mu t) \ ,$$
where $I_k$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Can the continuous solution be straightforwardly derived from the discrete solution by considering the adequate asymptotic behavior? If so, what is the correct limiting process?

On purely dimensional grounds, I would expect the convergence

$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\mathrm{e}^{-2D t/\varepsilon^2} I_{x/\varepsilon}(2D t/\varepsilon^2) \overset{\varepsilon\to0}{\longrightarrow} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/4 D t}}{\sqrt{4\pi D t}}$$
but it is not clear to me how carry out the limiting procedure.